# How to debug suspend?

Tags: suspend

I've been using Ubuntu for about five years now, and I still can't make it suspend when I want to. It's quite irritating that I can program up a storm, hack the machine in numerous other ways, and yet, and yet when I try to make it suspend or debug suspend, I fail miserably.

I need help.

Where do I begin to find the problem? What do I do to fix it? I'm placing a bounty on this, because I've literally lost hours of my life to this problem, and leaving my computer on ALL the time is terrible.

The symptoms:

- Pressing suspend brings my computer to a state where it has a blinking cursor, the fans are running, it seems that the HD has turned off (I think), and I can't do anything to bring it back from this state (short of a hard reboot).
- Possibly related: My fans stay on even after a shutdown, and even then, I have to press the power button for five seconds before I can start it up again.
- I don't know what logs to look at to debug the problem, and I imagine they'd get nuked on reboot anyway.

Please, please help. This drives me completely nuts, and I've been living with it for over a year.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm personally stuck initializing the graphics hardware. I could probably program my way out of it given enough time... but it would be much smoother to have some method for getting to the problem directly.

Comment: Yeah no luck. Apparently there's no method to debugging suspend, which is a bit shocking.

Comment: *How are you suspending?*  Are you running, from the command line `pm-suspend`?  Are you using a suspend key on your keyboard?  Are you making a call to acpi (e.g. /etc/acpi/sleep.sh or /etc/acpi/sleepbtn.sh)??

Comment: I'm just trying to use the very basic suspend button in the application menu. I think this just calls pm-suspend, right? I've tried other things too, but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: **To bounty hunters:** I'm looking mostly for general debugging recipes, i. e. information gathering, for more recent Ubuntu installations using systemd. My hope is that we can use this question as a canonical duplicate for broad suspend problem questions by inexperienced users.

Comment: I've always assumed that such problems are due to poor implementation of hardware standards rather than a failure of any particular OS.

Comment: @pbhj: Either way one needs a proper issue diagnosis as the first step on the path towards a solution.

Answer (score 23):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend

- Biggest problem is graphics hardware
- try suspend without restricted devices (nvidia, fglrx)
- kernel doesn't know how to handle graphical devices
- BIOS knows how to restore graphics state

  - via 16 bit segmented mode, C000:xxxx contains the visible 64k video ROM.
  - starting execution at C000:0003, normally re-POSTs the video BIOS (/usr/sbin/vbetool post)

    - more difficult in 64bit mode, since 16bit calls need to be emulated.
    - some memory is in 3-4G range, which requires remapping when emulating to avoid hitting the kernel which is mapped in the same space. 
      o video BIOS may have paged POST code out of C000 window
      o nvidia BIOS rewrites ROM to just return to stop re-POSTing 
      try suspend from console (via /etc/acpi/sleep.sh)
  - make sure you're logged out of Xorg (or run sleep.sh with "force" argument)
  - if the video BIOS isn't left in a sane state, returning to Xorg may hang the hardware
  - tests capslock on resume (if no capslock, kernel hung)
  - if backlight doesn't come back on, video BIOS probably didn't reinitialize
  - if screen is blank, but has a backlight, try hitting enter or switching between virtual terminals
  - try in single-user mode (via appending "single" to the grub kernel boot options)
  - for details on actions, try bash -x /etc/acpi/sleep.sh >/root/sleep.log 2>&1
  - look at dmidecode information that matches settings in /usr/share/acpi-support/*.config
  - if single-user mode console suspend or resume fails
  - PM trace (echo "1" > /sys/power/pm_trace) which will write device hashes to the system timer
  - attempt to suspend
  - after the failure, on reboot, examine the dmesg output for "device hash" entries to track down the device that hung the system during resume.
  - aware that this will reset the system clock, and fsck will freak out ("has gone without a fsck for 31337 days"). consider tune2fs -c 0 /dev/your/filesystems.

Comment: How do I turn off restricted devices?

Comment: any links to working scripts to sanity check a box when suspend fails ? ... this kind of issue is the bane of linux  and blocks mass usage ...

Answer (score 4):

You can find a lot of guidelines/advices [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

From your description, it sounds as if your ACPI is not working properly, or the kernel drivers are preventing a full suspend. The second link shows how to deal with that kind of problem.

Comment: I read these over, but they stop short of actually useful information for my problem. Need more help, and better particulars. I've created a bounty for this question.

Comment: Bad answer - just links. The point of the Stack*-sites is to provide a go-to place for all questions, not to send users on an endless goose-chase or say 'just f* google it'. Please insert your answer into the question and update it according to mlissner's comment.

Comment: Thanks: Sometimes it is useful to read the original homepage!

Answer (score 4):

The symptoms:

- Pressing suspend brings my computer to a state where it has a blinking cursor, the fans are running, it seems that the HD has turned off (I think), and I can't do anything to bring it back from this state (short of a hard reboot).
- Possibly related: My fans stay on even after a shutdown, and even then, I have to press the power button for five seconds before I can start it up again.
- I don't know what logs to look at to debug the problem, and I imagine they'd get nuked on reboot anyway.

---

My go to site for many Linux problems is Arch Linux. Here is what is posted about [suspend/resume problems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate) similar to yours:

### Instantaneous wakeups from suspend

For some Intel Haswell systems with the LynxPoint and LynxPoint-LP chipset, instantaneous wakeups after suspend are reported. They are linked to erroneous BIOS ACPI implementations and how the `xhci_hcd` module interprets it during boot. As a work-around reported affected systems are added to a blacklist (named `XHCI_SPURIOUS_WAKEUP`) by the kernel case-by-case.[[2](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171#c6)]

Instantaneous resume may happen, for example, if a USB device is plugged during suspend and ACPI wakeup triggers are enabled. A viable work-around for such a system, if it is not on the blacklist yet, is to disable the wakeup triggers. An example to disable wakeup through USB is described as follows.[[3](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1575617)]

To view the current configuration:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup

Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
...
EHC1      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC       S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
```

...

The relevant devices are `EHC1`, `EHC2` and `XHC` (for USB 3.0). To toggle their state you have to echo the device name to the file as root.

```
# echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
# echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
# echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

This should result in suspension working again. However, this settings are only temporary and would have to be set at every reboot. To automate this take a look at [systemd#Writing unit files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_unit_files). See [BBS thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1575617#p1575617) for a possible solution and more information.

---

The entire Arch Linux article above on Suspend/Resume is a great reference for many areas:

```
1 Low level interfaces
    1.1 kernel (swsusp)
    1.2 uswsusp
2 High level interfaces
    2.1 systemd
3 Hibernation
    3.1 About swap partition/file size
    3.2 Required kernel parameters
        3.2.1 Hibernation into swap file
    3.3 Configure the initramfs
4 Troubleshooting
    4.1 ACPI_OS_NAME
    4.2 VAIO Users
    4.3 Suspend/hibernate doesn't work, or not consistently
    4.4 Wake-on-LAN
    4.5 Instantaneous wakeups from suspend
```

Comment: Looks good! I'll wait another day or two to give others a chance to answer. Maybe somebody will feel inspired by yours. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks. It's challenging to answer an 8 year old question. There is also a suspend/resume problem with NVMe M.2 PCIe SSD's I will be adding tonight. These types of SSD's didn't exist in 2010 and require a special grub kernel argument.

Comment: I was looking less for solutions to specific suspend issues and more for general debugging recipes for more recent Ubuntu installations using systemd.

Comment: @DavidFoerster In that case I'll let the answer stand as is :)