# Suspend breaks on 12.10's kernel

Tags: suspend

I just installed installed 12.10, and suspend is not working.
Here are more details:

- When I select suspend from the power menu, the screen goes black (with the monitor still running), but the computer is still running. Num Lock works, but Caps Lock doesn't work [*]. The computer never enters suspend mode, but I can't get the monitor to respond either. The only way I can get out of this situation is to shut down the machine by holding the power button.
- When I forcefully reboot it, I get the message "Ubuntu 12.10 has encountered an internal error". Apparently something is wrong with apportcheckresume.
- I googled a bit and found this [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1062470). I installed the amd64 kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7-rc1-quantal/); on this new kernel suspend **works**. But there are no drivers, so it's not a solution.

So, the question is:

1. How do I fix suspend on the current kernel (3.5.0-17-generic); OR
2. How do I install drivers on the mainline kernel?

A solution to either will solve the problem.

--

[*] [How to debug suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16239/how-to-debug-suspend) seem to suggest this is a kernel hang?

Comment: I have something similar. Suspend won't work if I press my power button, then click on the suspend button. But it will suspend by closing the lid, or clicking suspend from the dropdown from the top bar. Is weird.

Comment: I posted the same question [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12308434#post12308434). There is more discussion, if anyone is interested.

Comment: I have similar problem. I opened a launchpad report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1069707

Comment: It seems like a bug and hence off-topic for the site.