# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after resuming from sleep mode

Tags: 18.04

I've made a clean installation for Ubuntu 18.04 but I face a strange behavior after resuming the machine after sleeping mode. I get the errors as in the following shot.
My machine is HP ProBook 450 g4 with Evo 860 SSD.

[image]

Comment: Here are a few useful links: [SO Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16239/how-to-debug-suspend), [Understanding Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend), [Debugging Kernel Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).