# How can I find out what causes X to crash?

Tags: suspend, crash

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/64530a7684dc55f05c856a55d60bcb22) has a section from my syslog from the point of suspend to resuming, which ultimately caused X to crash. But I cannot find out which program or service was the actual culprit ... Is there anything from the syslog which is the obvious sinner?

```
Jun 19 17:20:46 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc [GTK=CCMP]
Jun 19 17:28:26 e6330 pulseaudio[31070]: W: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.5642] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.5710] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 gnome-shell[31045]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 gnome-shell[31045]: Failed to set power save mode for output LVDS-1: Permission denied
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.7631] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.7950] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::55d8:3e2d:6360:269 on wlp2s0.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::55d8:3e2d:6360:269.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.8988] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4680
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.8989] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.100.133 on wlp2s0.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.100.133.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422121.9308] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 kernel: [74145.847566] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun 19 17:28:41 e6330 whoopsie[1345]: [17:28:41] offline
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 dbus-daemon[904]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.16' (uid=0 pid=914 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 gsd-sharing[31821]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 gsd-sharing[31821]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 gsd-sharing[31821]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 gsd-sharing[31821]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service not loaded.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 dbus-daemon[904]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [wlp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 kernel: [74146.271640] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]: Suspending system...
Jun 19 17:28:42 e6330 kernel: [74146.271642] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74146.373131] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.029 seconds) done.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74146.402655] OOM killer disabled.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74146.402656] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... 
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.324663] (elapsed 6.922 seconds) done.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]: System resumed.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 rtkit-daemon[1252]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 rtkit-daemon[1252]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 rtkit-daemon[1252]: Demoted 0 threads.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.324706] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.338356] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.342880] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.379078] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.506865] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.550763] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.550764] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.550765] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.550783] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.566860] IRQ 28: no longer affine to CPU1
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.567876] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.587854] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.610720] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU3
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.610730] IRQ 30: no longer affine to CPU3
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.611739] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.613571] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.613627] ACPI: EC: EC started
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 google-chrome.desktop[12557]: [12557:12575:0619/172921.436188:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(403)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.613627] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.613969] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.614048] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.614049] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.616564]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.616822] CPU1 is up
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.616853] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.619311]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.619536] CPU2 is up
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.619565] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.622002]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.622417] CPU3 is up
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74153.625927] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74154.077382] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74154.080235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74154.709912] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74154.709914] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.014866] OOM killer enabled.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.014866] Restarting tasks ... done.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.052409] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.052423] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.052441] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.052458] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.064880] acpi PNP0401:00: Already enumerated
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.083897] acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.122537] PM: suspend exit
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.596166] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.596248] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.756218] ata1.00: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 330)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.756234] ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.759160] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.759167] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.759171] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74155.765540] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422161.5099] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 20:16:D8:97:AA:44
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422161.5121] bluez5: NAP: added interface 20:16:D8:97:AA:44
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-rfkill[14446]: Failed to open device rfkill16: No such device
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]: /dev/sda:
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]:  APM_level#011= 128
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]: /dev/sda:
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd-sleep[14309]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422161.8614] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422161.8615] device (eno1): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74156.575807] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 gnome-shell[31045]: Failed to set power save mode for output LVDS-1: Permission denied
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422161.9683] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:21 e6330 kernel: [74156.582687] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 goa-daemon[31772]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 google-chrome.desktop[12557]: [12557:12557:0619/172922.138320:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 at-spi-bus-launcher[31698]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 at-spi-bus-launcher[31698]:       after 18829 requests (18829 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422162.1873] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74156.800355] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 google-chrome.desktop[12557]: [12601:12601:0619/172922.213563:ERROR:x11_util.cc(90)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[31720]: Gdk-Message: 17:29:22.221: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74156.847330] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74156.860440] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-shell[31720]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 [31832]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-clipboard[31849]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-terminal-[32304]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[31720]: Gdk-Message: 17:29:22.346: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-media-keys[31861]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 update-notifier[355]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-power[31813]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-wacom[31840]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-color[31856]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 firefox[10518]: firefox: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[31720]: Sandbox: Unexpected EOF, op 2 flags 00 path /etc/localtime
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74157.110810] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 bluetoothd[884]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.291 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74157.209997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422162.5983] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422162.6965] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74157.310768] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422162.6967] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-shell[14514]: Failed to create backend: Unable to open display ':0'
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session[31606]: gnome-session-binary[31606]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gnome-session-binary[31606]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 systemd[31579]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 systemd[31579]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-color[31111]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Display_carlerik_1000
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 kernel: [74157.483868] rfkill: input handler enabled
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-keyboard[31869]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Jun 19 17:29:22 e6330 gsd-printer[31885]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.6 was not provided by any .service files
Jun 19 17:29:23 e6330 goa-daemon[31772]: secret_password_lookup_sync() returned NULL
Jun 19 17:29:24 e6330 ModemManager[919]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0': not supported by any plugin
Jun 19 17:29:24 e6330 ModemManager[919]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8310] policy: auto-activating connection 'breiband'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8320] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'breiband' (eb1aaa3e-1dc0-4296-8772-94fb09a1365b)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8322] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8324] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8330] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8332] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'breiband' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8333] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8334] sup-iface[0x556a7134e390,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8372] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8376] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8377] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'breiband' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8380] Config: added 'ssid' value 'breiband'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8380] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8380] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8381] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8381] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8381] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc (SSID='breiband' freq=2462 MHz)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.464063] wlp2s0: authenticate with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.465414] wlp2s0: send auth to ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc (try 1/3)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc (SSID='breiband' freq=2462 MHz)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8557] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> associating
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.468140] wlp2s0: authenticated
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.476072] wlp2s0: associate with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc (try 1/3)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.479874] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: Associated with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.487069] wlp2s0: associated
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8791] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to ec:08:6b:ff:d3:bc completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 kernel: [74160.495890] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8873] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8873] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'breiband'.
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8874] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8888] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.8945] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 14544
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 dhclient[14544]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.100.133 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1e2aeb94)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 dhclient[14544]: DHCPACK of 192.168.100.133 from 192.168.100.1
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.9744] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.100.133
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1529422165.9745] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 19 17:29:25 e6330 avahi-daemon[889]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.100.133.
```

Comment: What graphics do you have oligofren? I always assume (often wrongly) that nVidia are to blame for everything :) A bit more info about your machine and what you're running might help out - is it Ubuntu 18.04? Do you have the same problem with a Wayland session? What processor and what graphics do you have?

Comment: Also, found this link as an answer to a different question about suspend but could be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16239/how-to-debug-suspend

Comment: Search on `xorg log` to get the log file name. I'm on my phone...

Comment: it could be this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device/1050201#1050201

Answer (score 1):

If you log in again after the resume, you should hopefully see be able to a crash message if you look at the end of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, or possibly `$HOME/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log.old`.  That is, in the Xorg log file from your previous login.

[There is a particular known issue on Ubuntu 18.04, which I think matches everything you describe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device/1050201#1050201).  It generates crashes at many different locations, but it also has quite a distinct feature.  The crash always occurs with a SIGBUS signal - "bus error" - which is quite unusual (on common Intel/AMD-style x86 cpus).

Most crashes occur with the signal SIGSEGV ("segmentation fault") or SIGABRT (assertion failure / abort).  SIGSEGV is the common error for accessing a null pointer or wild pointer, particularly on x86.  Note that for SIGSEGV on x86, Linux logs a "segfault" message, which would have appeared in the system log.  This SIGBUS crash often doesn't leave a distinct signature in the system log!  So already I am suspecting the known issue.  Since you are using software affected by this nasty bug, I would suggest you look at it and see if you can rule it out by testing one of the suggested workarounds.  But I'm not sure if that answers the general sense of your question.

There are a couple of different messages which *sometimes* occur with this SIGBUS crash.  If you wanted to, you could search through all your historical logs and see if you had any "Read-error on swap device", or any "Buffer I/O error".  E.g. `zgrep -C5 /var/log/kern* "Read-error"`.

Note that Xorg logs its own crashes but this is quite an unusual thing for software to do.  It tries to catch crashes, logging the crash signal and where they happened in the code, including the full chain of function calls that led up to it.  **In theory, the call-chain might be something useful to search for other reports.**  Unfortunately when I've tried to rely on this, the call-chain logged by Xorg seems to be inaccurate, and can look basically the same for problems which are actually different.

To capture crash location it is more reliable to use a general-purpose system such as Ubuntu Apport or systemd-coredump.  I'm familiar with the latter.  If you installed `systemd-coredump` it would capture a full coredump of the crashes and allow you to inspect them using `coredumpctl`.  Installing systemd-coredump would remove Ubuntu Apport though.

Unfortunately I don't use Ubuntu, and I know very little about how Apport behaves.  I read that the full Ubuntu Apport isn't enabled by default on stable releases.  Specifically, I think stable releases do not enable the feature that lets you create bug reports which could be searched for on the open web.  Clearly, enabling it would take you longer than using the `Xorg.log`, and it will reduce the number of people who report using this method.  So if the `Xorg.log` information is not 100% accurate but is *distinct*, it is possible you might have more luck searching for reports of crashes using the `Xorg.log` information, even where it is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It is surly NVIDIA driver or NVIDIA proprietary driver compatibility issue with Ubuntu kernel.

I am having NVIDIA 740M GPU on laptop  and I was facing same issue.
Whenever I used to  put down laptop lid or used to suspend laptop then upon resuming X was failing to turn-on. and some time it is used to show error something like

> GPU is fallen out the bus.

But when I turned off the NVIDIA GPU from BIOS  I am able to suspend and resume OS smoothly

`