# can't suspend my computer cause of amd gpu

Tags: suspend, 22.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I recently got a rx 560 for my computer running ubuntu 22.04 and installed the amdgpu drivers which worked. Though now when I try to suspend my computer the monitor goes blank for a second, then comes right back on like nothing even happened. Before I had an gtx 650 ti installed in the computer which worked fine when tryng to suspend, but now with the rx 560 it does not suspend. I then tried the pm-suspend command and it worked just fine so now I need to know how to either implement the pm-suspend command or just fix suspend.

I have a desktop computer and I use the power button on it to suspend and also have a shortcut I made that uses `systemctl suspend`. Both of those have the same exact thing happen as described above.

[My System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYBN9.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "installed the amdgpu drivers"?. That sounds awfully suspicious. Btw I assume this OS had previously running the NV card?

Comment: like if I run `lshw -c video` in the configuration tab it says `driver=amdgpu` and yes before I upgraded I had the NV card running just fine.

Comment: The thing is `amdgpu` is already included in any modern Linux distro and automatically activated for any compatible hardware. **You DON'T need to install the AMD proprietary drivers** (AKA `amdgpu-pr`).

Comment: I know that and I think I am using that, the only reason I don't know for sure is because I tried to install the proprietary drivers, and that caused problems, but I think I'm on the default ones

Comment: Ok first make sure suspend is also broken in a Live USB environment. I say this, because you previously had NV, and NV drivers tend to mess up the system. If the problem persists, make sure your BIOS is not in CSM but rather in pure UEFI, and then check https://askubuntu.com/questions/16239/how-to-debug-suspend and check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Comment: So in a live boot suspend works just fine, so like you said how do I get rid of the NV drivers and stuff. Also what information about the debugging suspend would be useful to you @MatiasNGoldberg

Comment: Honestly IDK because it could be a million things (misbehaving USB device, a lingering monitor xorg conf file, Wake on Lan). The first thing you should do is run `sudo dmesg` as soon as it resumes to see if some useful error rings a bell. But probably formatting and reinstalling is going to be faster.

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg what about the NV drivers that could be the problem. I wouldn't know what to look for or how to get rid of them.

Comment: Also just looking at the logs it seems when I execute `systemctl suspend` the computer goes to sleep for a second but just then just wake back up.

[Here part of the log](https://pastebin.com/nNy6KHSt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out just updating my kernel from 5.13 to 5.15 solved the suspend problem.

Instructions to install 5.15 kernel:  [here](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-15-on-ubuntu-20-04/)